# Checking if file with file-extension '.ini' exists, shell

Tags: file, shell, exists, file-extension

How do I check (with the shell) if a file with the file-extension `.ini` exists in `/dir`? 
What would be the fastest way? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set -- /dir/*.ini
case $1 in
  ('/dir/*.ini') echo "No ini files here.";;
  (*)            echo "Found $# ini files: $@";;
esac
```

Look ma! No forks! This should beat, by a million of CPU cycles, any solution with forks to `ls`, `find` and friends.

Now there's one little gotcha here. Can you spot it? Okay, what happens if `/dir` contains a file named `*.ini` literally (star, dot, ini)? The above will give you a *false negative*: it reports *no* ini file although there is one. If you want to prepare for this case (and you should, because you are a careful programmer, giving attention to detail, no gotchas in *your* code, right?), you slightly modify the first case to read

```
('/dir/*.ini')
  if test -f '/dir/*.ini'; then
    echo "Wow, there's a plain file named '/dir/*.ini'!"
  else
    echo "No ini files here."
  fi;;
```

Answer (score 5):

I´ve found this one usefull to verify existing jpeg files.

```
if ls /path/*.jpg &> /dev/null; then
    #do something with existing files
else
    echo "files do not exist"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

`find /dir/ -iname '*.ini'`. If you want to not search subdirectories, add `-maxdepth 1` after `/dir/`